# How do i calculate Birthdays from Customer Day and Month of Birth in Qlikview?

Tags: qlikview

I want to use my dashboard in qlikview to always fetch the Customers that their birthday is today. so that our Customer Care Department can easily see those celebrating birthday today.

Any help please...?

Comment: How often do you load your data? There are different options depending on this

Answer (score 1):

If you're loading your data every day, you can create a new field that returns 1 if the birthday is today.

```
Load CustomerName
,if(MakeDate(2016,Month(Birthday),Day(Birthday))=Today(),1,0) as BirthdayFlag
```

Then create a chart, select a straight table, add your customer name as the dimension and the BirthdayFlag as the Expression.

If you aren't loading every day, you can create the straight table below and add the expression

```
Max(if(MakeDate(2016,Month(Birthday),Day(Birthday))=Today(),1,0))
```

This doesn't cater for leap year babies on the 29th February - however you can cater for this if needed with with some if statements